# I am not able to customize EXTRA theme image in single post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am running one website that is [link] (http://webglut.com) in wordpress and I am using a theme called 'EXTRA'. But I am not able to customize featured image as it is showing big by default, what ever the size of image  I am uploading is not showing original rather showing big.

Please check a single post [link] ( http://webglut.com/howto/how-to-upload-video-on-youtube-and-earn-from-the-same/)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *functions.php* and locate the [set_post_thumbnail_size()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) function. Change it to the width and height of your choosing, for example:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 700, 400 );
```

Also, you have this in CSS that resizes your thumbnail image to the `width:100%` :

```
.post-thumbnail img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You might want to remove that line.